# How to automatically add timestamps eg. createdAt/updatedAt in MongoDB nodejs driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a small application and I need to automatically add a timestamp of creating/updating my documents in the default Nodejs MongoDb driver. Right now, when I add a new document, it only has added the `_id` field. Is there a way to force the addition of the `createdAt/updatedAt` fields?

Comment: Assuming you are using mongoose, add `timestamps: true` option inside your `mongoose.schema`. This will add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields for every document inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers do not generally provide this functionality. ODMs do. In case of Node, mongoose is an ODM which does.

Answer (score 0):

You can add createdAt manually when creating the object this way:

```
        await this.collection.insertOne({ businessAuth: _id, url, labels, createdAt: new Date()});
```

And updatedAT when updating the object this way:

```
video.updatedAt = new Date();
const saved = await this.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: video._id}, {$set: {...video}});
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically add timestamps for creating and updating documents in MongoDB using the default Node.js MongoDB driver, you can leverage the timestamps option provided by Mongoose. Here's how you can modify your existing schema to include createdAt and `updatedAt` fields:

```js
const SchemaName = new Schema({  ....... }, {   timestamps: true })
```

It will create the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields automatically and also update their values on every time on performing create and update operation.